# Inserting at the end of linked list. Why S node becoming null at each insertion

Tags: c++

```cpp
void insertnode(node *s, int a)
{
    node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = a;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if(s==NULL)
    {
        s = newnode;
    }
    else
    {  
        node *p = s;
        while(p->next!=NULL)
        {
             p=p->next;
        }
        p->next = newnode;
   }
}
int main()
{
    node *s;
    insertnode(s,5); //inserting element at the end

    insertnode(s,10); //inserting element at the end
    return 0;
}
```

Not able to understand as why s is still null at each 
insertion. Printing after insertion producing no output.
*Pardon me for asking beginners doubts*

Comment: Undefined behavior. `s` is not initialized before it's used, on top of all the other problems, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` is null after every insertion because your code `s = newnode` is setting the local `s` pointer to a new value, which does not updated the contents of the original pointer in `main()`. You could either have `insertnode()` return the `s` pointer (e.g., `s = insertnode(s,5)`, not recommended), or have `main()` create a [sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) as a beginning-of-list placeholder that you then pass to `insertnode()` on the first call to it (recommended).